# Can someone explain this behavior for interaction model of Alexa Skill?

Tags: nlp, alexa-skills-kit

This is the interaction model I am using:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "greeter",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "HelloWorldIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "phrase",
                            "type": "phrase"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{phrase}"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "phrase",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "HelloWorldIntent asdf {phrase}"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the value of phrase slot type. When I set it this way, whatever I say to alexa, whole of the raw query is getting populated in value field of phrase slot of the request object.

Ex:

"Launch greeter" ==> LaunchIntent (obvious)

"No matter what I say it triggers Hello world intent" ==>

```
"intent": {
        "name": "HelloWorldIntent",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "slots": {
            "phrase": {
                "name": "phrase",
                "value": "no matter what I say it triggers hello world intent",
                "resolutions": {
                    "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                        {
                            "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.6c1d0991-f895-45fa-ba37-6880d3cc95f1.phrase",
                            "status": {
                                "code": "ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not able to figure out how this interaction model is giving me the raw query in "value" field of phrase slot.

Comment: You need to add more sample phrases to your intent. And try to use your slots to get information crucial information for your intent, not the whole sentence (not just {Phrase}, add a sentence like *"this is a sentence where you would use {Phrase}"*).

Comment: Consider this like a **fill in the blanks** . Now if you had a sample like *"My name is {Name}"* and one just *"{Name}"*, the skill is bound to fill the sample phrase that matches the closest to the utterance said by the user. So use them wisely.